# Is it possible to cache/externalize each frame in beamer?

Tags: beamer, tikz-external

Is it somehow possible to cache or externalize each frame in beamer? Similar functionality exists for TikZ pictures (TikZ library "externalize"). The purpose is to speed up the process by compiling the changed frames only.

Comment: Externalization relies on `\includegraphics`, this would remove any interactive features from your frames, such as links.

Answer (score 4):

My option for speeding up compilation is using `\includeonlyframes`(*). So, I have in my preamble, just before the `\begin{document}`:

```
\includeonlyframes{title,working,also1,also2}% no spaces between labels!
```

and the frame I am working with has

```
\begin{frame}[label=working]
...
\end{frame}
```

Now, just this frame is compiled. When finished, I change the label to a definitive one (or none) and go on by putting the `working` label to the new frame.

I normally compile always the title frame (by using `label=title`) to have a minimum of one frame, and also other frames for reference (for that I use the `also1`, `also2`... labels).

You just need to comment/uncomment the `\includeonlyframes` line to switch to compile the full presentation.

(*) thanks to @samcarter for the hint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the method I have been using. I wonder whether there are other solutions since I also want to browse through the slides from time to time when I edit.

Comment: @FluffyCat in chat, [@samcarter](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56177742#56177742) suggested to have a look at https://github.com/misc0110/beamer-preview or https://github.com/theHamsta/faster-beamer --- never used them, though. If you try them and find them useful you can self-respond here!